# Append a character to the out using unix command

Tags: linux, unix

`echo 20220506 | cut -c5-6`
gives the output as

```
05
```

I want add a '/' at the end of the output(05/). Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo 20220506 | cut -c5-6 | sed 's/$/\//'
```

Sed is stream editor and `s/$/\//` means

```
s : substitute
$ : end of line
\/ : / escaped with \
other slashes (/) : separator character of parameters to substitution operator.
```

Comment: Not that you can also eliminate the `cut` and just do: `echo 20220506 | sed -e 's@....\(..\).*@\1/@'`. (But that gets unwieldy and is harder to read.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a pipe `|` character, you could use backticks to evaluate your command inside another command.

```
echo `echo 20220506 | cut -c5-6`/

> 05/
```

Comment: Please use `$()` instead of backticks.  It's several decades now since backticks should be considered effectively obsolete.

Comment: Good point.   It really depends on which shell is being used.   Some of us still need to use csh (tcsh).   In csh, `$()` is not a thing.   I forgot that most people are using bash or a successor to bash.